# stability of telegraph equation or damped wave equation using the energy integral method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, stability-theory

I have the next equation

$ u_{tt} - k^2 u_{xx} + 2 \alpha u_t = 0 \quad $ with $u = u(x,t)$

where $ x \in (0, L)$ and $t\geq 0$.

this equation is called "telegraph equation" or "damped wave equation" and this equation seems like wave equation, so to prove the stability of the solutions I tried to use the integral energy but I don't how to use it. I prove that the energy decresing:

Suppose  that:

$u(L,t)=u(0,t)=0 $ $\forall t\geq 0$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$

$u_t(x,0)=g(x)$

Be $k, \alpha > 0$, and  $x \in (-\infty , \infty)$.  Let
$$ E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(u_t^2 + k^2 u_x^2\right)\; dx $$

Then
$$ E'(t) =   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(u_t u_{tt} + k^2 u_x u_{xt}\right)\; dx$$
Integrate the second term by parts, and apply the PDE:

$$ \eqalign{E'(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(u_t u_{tt} - k^2 u_{xx} u_t\right)\; dx\cr
&= - 2 \alpha \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2 \; dx \le 0}$$

and now I don't what to do! some hint or idea? exist another method to prove the stability?

I want stability in the sense that for exemple, if $u$ satisfied

$u_{tt} - k^2 u_{xx} + 2 \alpha u_t = 0$

$u(L,t)=u(0,t)=0 $

$u(x,0)=f1(x)$

$u_t(x,0)=g1(x)$

and v satified

$v_{tt} - k^2 v_{xx} + 2 \alpha v_t = 0$

$v(L,t)=v(0,t)=0 $

$v(x,0)=f2(x)$

$v_t(x,0)=g2(x)$

such that $||f1-f2|| < \epsilon $ and $|||g1-g2|| < \epsilon $ so $||u-v|| < \epsilon $ with the norm in $L_2$

Comment: So $E(t)$ is decreasing in time.

Comment: yes, but why that implies stability? I edit the sense that I want the stability

Comment: You can write $u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty U(\omega,t) e^{i \omega x}d\omega$ so that $\|u(.,t)\|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \|U(.,t)\|^2$ and the equation becomes $U_{tt} - k^2 (i\omega)^2 U + 2 \alpha U_t = 0$

Comment: I don´t get it, I don´t understand how to prove stability starting from this D: